# What is the change of basis in 2D?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know how to apply a change of basis in 1D, but I was wondering: If I want to apply a change of basis to a nxn matrix, is it enough to apply the change of basis to every column of the matrix or is this a different process?

Comment: This is a very strange question, unless you mean something else by "1D" and "2D" than the rest of the world... Could you try to clarify, please?

Comment: Sure. What I'm trying to say is that I know that to apply a change of basis to a vector, I just have to multiply it by some change of basis matrix. But, what if I want to apply the change of basis to a matrix? Is it enough to multiply its rows with the change of basis matrix?

Comment: I see, you mean matrix = "2-dimensional array" as in programming. In mathematics, "2D" usually refers to vectors with 2 coordinates, and 2-by-2 matrices...

Comment: Oh, sorry about the misunderstanding. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P$ is the matrix which defines the change of the basis (its columns are the coordinates of the new basis vectors in terms of the old basis), then – as you say who know – the formula $X=PX'$ (or equivalently $X'=P^{-1}X$) relates the old ($X$) and new ($X'$) coordinates of a vector.

Now, if you have a linear transformation $Y=AX$ described in the old basis, you get
$$
Y' = P^{-1}Y = P^{-1}AX = P^{-1}APX'
,
$$
so that the matrix $P^{-1}AP$ is what describes the same transformation in the new basis.